# How can I find the longest record (in characters) for each column in a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, table, postgis

I couldn't find the answer to this on here so sorry if repeated. I'm looking to query a table to find the longest record in characters for each column in a specific table.

I have a table which is built of fields which are **type: varchar** and **length:254**

In certain cases, I know for a fact that the longest record is a single character so the problem is when exporting to shapefiles the .dbf file is over 1gb when not needed.

If someone can also help with a script to reduce the lengths of each column as well that would be great!

Comment: Shortening the metadata type restriction will however not use less space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below worked for what I needed:

```
SELECT
        MAX(char_length(column1)) as column1,
        MAX(char_length(column2)) as column2
FROM
        schema.table
```